# Selecting div within anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

How to select div tag inside an anchor tag. Consider the following HTML.

```
<a target="_new" href="https://stackoverflow.com/12.mp4"
       data-placement="top" rel="tooltip" 
       title="Video (MP4)" >
       <div class="hidden">Interesting 12</div>
    </a>
```

I have to select all anchor tags pointing to video resource. I am able to select the anchor tags. Now How do I select the division inside it and get the text?

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if (typeof link == "string" && link.indexOf(".mp4") > 0) {
        alert(link);
    }
})​
```

Comment: I'm guessing `$(this).find('.hidden').text()` inside the loop would do that!

Comment: It is not valid to place a `div` inside of an anchor element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.find('div')` or `.find('.hidden')` after your `$('a')`

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href*=".mp4"]').each(function() {
   alert( this.href );
   $(this).find('div.hidden').text();
});
```

OR

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if (typeof link == "string" && link.indexOf(".mp4") > 0) {
        alert(link);

        $(this).find('div.hidden').text();
        // OR
        $('div.hidden', this).text();
    }
})​;
```

#### NOTE

Placing a `div` within anchor tag is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").each(function(){
    $(this).find('div').each(function(){
        ....
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if (typeof link == "string" && link.indexOf(".mp4") > 0) {
        alert(link);
    }

    // get the div
    var divText = $(this).find('div').text();

})​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").each(function() {

    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    a=link.length;

    var filetype=link[a-3]+link[a-2]+link[a-1]

    if(link[a-4] == '.' && filetype=='mp4') //you can check more extensions here using ||.
      $(this).find('.hidden').text()          


})
```